# Custom ActionBar not workinh in android 4 or higher

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-custom-view

I used this site to generate a custom actionbar to my app.

It is woking fine on older devices ( API 9,10, etc), but in android 4 it show the default HoloLight ActionBar.

Here is my custom styles that came from the site.

```
<resources>

<style name="Theme.Politify" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">

    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_politify</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Politify</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Politify</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Politify</item>
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Politify</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Transparent.Politify</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_politify</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_politify</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Politify</item>

    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_politify</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Politify</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Politify</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Politify</item>
    <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Politify</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Transparent.Politify</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_politify</item>
    <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_politify</item>
    <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Politify</item>



</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Politify" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_solid_politify</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_politify</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_politify</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Politify</item>

    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_politify</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_politify</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_politify</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Politify</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Politify" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_transparent_politify</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Politify</item>

    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_transparent_politify</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Politify</item>
</style>

<!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
<style name="Theme.Politify.Widget" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Politify</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Politify</item>

    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Politify</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Politify</item>
</style>
```

And here is the part of the manifest that I import this style.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Politify" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Example Action Bar Theme](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#StyleExample):

> Notice that there are two version for each action bar style property. The first one includes the `android:` prefix on the property name to support API levels 11 and higher that include these properties in the framework. The second version does not include the `android:` prefix and is for older versions of the platform, on which the system uses the style property from the support library. The effect for each is the same.

As you only have the non-prefixed versions, the styles are only applied to <11 API levels.

Comment: I edit my answer with the changes. It still didn`t work. In fact, where I put the "android:.." I got same erros like "required API 13, current is 8". I ran it even with the hints but nothing change. Am I doing something wrong again?

Comment: Those are [Lint](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/improving-w-lint.html) errors, stating that the `android:` prefix don't do anything on lower API levels. You can safely ignore them (as the system will ignore attributes it doesn't know about) or split your `styles.xml` into a default one (which would only have the non-prefixed) and one in `values-v11` (or `values-v13`, etc) until you have no more lint errors.

Comment: Thanks it works fine now. The only problem that I have is the color of the title. In fact, the newer devices seems to connect the title and the icon in the same icon. There is a solution for this?

Comment: The color of the title text and title selected background should match the action bar items - what color are you referring to?

Comment: In older devices the color of the activity title is purple ( the correct color) but in newer devices it still black ( default Holo Light color). And in older devices when I click the icon is just the icon, but in newer when I click the icon ( like up button ) it shows the icon and the title as the same clickable area.